# How to bind LINQ results to DataGrid, only one column?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a DataGrid in my View with `ItemsSource="{Binding GetValues, Mode=TwoWay}"`.

In my ViewModel:
private List getValues = new List();

```
public List<Language> GetValues
{
    get { return getValues; }
    set { SetField("GetValues", ref getValues, value); }
}
```

In this case, everything is fine:

```
DatabaseDataContext myDB = new DatabaseDataContext();
var query = myDB.Languages.Where(u => u.Valid == true).ToList();
GetValues = query;
```

But I want to get in my DataGrid only one column, so tried this:

```
DatabaseDataContext myDB = new DatabaseDataContext();
var query = myDB.Languages
                       .Where(u => u.Valid == true)
                       .Select(u => new { Name = u.Title });
GetValues = query.ToList();
```

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'"

Is there a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** is that the `query returns a anonymous object` and you try to assign this list of anonymous object to a list of Language type.

**Solution** Change your Linq `query to select a object of type Language` rather than anonymous object.

This must help

```
var query = myDB.Languages
                       .Where(u => u.Valid == true)
                       .Select(u => new Language { Title = u.Title });
```

Then when you do a `.ToList()` on it the result and the data type of `GetValues` will match.

Comment: You are right, but another way: he could simply change GetValues to be `List<string>` and just `.Select(u => u.Title );`. Won't work if he definitely wants to use a list of `Language` type though.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Yes true, But I assume he wants to use the `Language` itself instead of a `string` because he mentions that he wants to populate the DataGrid and with only one column, that means there will be other columns too with default value / null.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the type of `GetValues` is `List<Language>`, but you try to set it to dynamically created anonymous type. To solve the problem you should create a new class which represents your needed data.

```
public class LanguageTitle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other needed properties
}
```

Then add property to your view model:

```
public List<LanguageTitle> LanguageTitles
{
    get { return languageTitles; }
    set { SetField("GetLanguageTitles", ref languageTitles, value); }
}
```

In your query select `LanguageTitle`:

```
DatabaseDataContext myDB = new DatabaseDataContext();
var query = myDB.Languages
                       .Where(u => u.Valid == true)
                       .Select(u => new LanguageTitle { Name = u.Title });
LanguageTitles = query.ToList();
```

And bind your `DataGrid` to this property:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageTitles, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would have a object that have:

```
public List<Language> GetValues
{
    get { return getValues; }
    set { SetField("GetValues", ref getValues, value); }
}
```

but you don't want all the properties filled from that object. It is a bad practise so re-use object because their almost simular. 
You might want to change your property GetValues into

```
public List<string> GetValues {get;set;}
```

Then in your linq-query you can use:

```
GetValues = myDB.Languages
                   .Where(u => u.Valid == true)
                   .Select(u =>  u.Title)
                   .ToList();
```